# sed addressing for each of multiple input files

Tags: file, parsing, sed, tail

I would like to print from line 10 until the end of the file for each of several files in a folder.  For a single file, I would do this with `sed -n '10,$p'`, however when providing multiple input files to sed the addressing becomes in terms of the concatenated files.  How can I print using the sed command and address each file's line numbers?  [This website](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html) says that the $ addressing character refers to each file's end if the -s option is used, but this does not work for me on my Macbook Pro.

Ideally I would like the whole procedure to be done with a single tool without writing a loop.  I'm ok with the output being concatenated.  I'm open to other tools than sed.  `tail` might work for this like so `tail -n +10 filenames` but this is very very slow, so I imagine `sed` is better to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR>9{print $0}' file1 file2
```

This will do it

Comment: Actually `awk 'FNR>9{print $0}' files`.  Thanks

Comment: If someone can post how to do it with `sed` that would be lovely